# Realtime Twitter streaming on Linux

Tags: linux, software-rec, twitter

Tweetdeck has the ability to show messages in real time. I have not been able to find this capability in any other client that I've tried. The latest versions of Tweetdeck don't run on Linux. Is there any twitter client for Linux that can do real-time streaming?

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled upon [Hotot](http://hotot.org/features.html) which writes "Real-time Update - Update your timeline in real-time" on their webpage.

Tweetdeck isn't working either as [Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hbdpomandigafcibbmofojjchbcdagbl)?

Comment: Tweetdeck in Chrome doesn't update in real-time, it just checks for new messages.